# Google Drive API - determine if a video file has finished processing

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to programmatically determine if a video added to Google Drive has finished converting/"processing"?  As far as I can see nothing changes in the files->get response before and after it has finished processing.

(PHP Client Library)

Comment: Good question. The property that I would expect to change would be the md5Checksum, ie. I don't see how it could not change if the content is being processed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `thumbnailLink` attribute exists, video file has finished processing. It's not truly the official way to see the processing status but, as a workaround you can depend on that.

Comment: Sorry took awhile to accept this answer, ran a few tests and can verify that it works, the thumbnailLink doesnt exist until it finishes processing.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be to try using a different browser and reuploading your video or else you can clear your browsing cache and cookies because it might create problems while uploading the video on Google drive.

Please refer to this article on [google drive still processing the video](https://geekydane.com/google-drive-still-processing-video/) if you need to see the methods to solve this issue